# Implement iterator next-method for a HashMap - How?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I'm in a bit of a struggle with overriding the Next-method for my implemented Iterator. I want to return the elements one by one, but I can't seem to figure out how to, anyone want to enlighten me? At the moment my code looks like:

```
public E next() {
    if (iteratorCount == map.size()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
```

I've done this several times using an ArrayList, but this seems to be quite different?

Comment: HashMap already provides an iterator.

Comment: What semantics do you think `next` on a map should have? Are you looking to iterate over the keys or the values or a combination thereof?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick response! I know that HashMap provides an iterator, but I want to Override and create my own. I want to iterate over the elements and return them.

Comment: At the moment code doesn't look helpful to us, can you dump complete implementation which you came up at least the whole `next` method..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterator` as follows. why you are trying to create your own iterator?

```
    Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
    Iterator valueIterator=map.values().iterator(); // iterate through values
    Iterator keyIterator=map.keySet().iterator();   // iterate through keys

    //then 
    valueIterator.next();// for next value in the map
    keyIterator.next();// for the next key in the map
```

Now you can iterate thought map by key and return them as follows.

```
     while (keyIterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(map.get(keyIterator.next()));
     }
```

Comment: It's an exercise we have been provided, asking us to make a Set<E> extending AbstractCollection<E>. We want to create a HashMap<E, Integer> and override a bunch of methods, among Iterator<E> iterator().